# In the css when i call the page i load the one link with coding and other by hyperlink the code link size expand big?

Tags: css

In the css when i call the page  i load the one  link with coding and other by  hyperlink the code link  size  expand big?

Comment: Tip: If your title is the same as the question, the title is too long or the question is too short. Or both.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly not a CSS question. The problem isn't really with the CSS or that CSS is handled differently for dynamically created elements, because it isn't.

There is something that you do differently when creating link elements dynamically that makes them different from the ones created with markup code. When the page arrives at the browser, there is no way to determine which elements are rendered from dynamically generated controls, so the difference is what the rendered elements contain. This difference will be visible if you view the source code of the page in the browser.

Comment: @anup: From the information that you have given, I can't really tell you anything more. I have already extrapolated far beyond the information in the question, going further would be plain guesswork, and the chance that I would happen to make the right guess about what you are doing is minimal. You have to give a lot more information in your question about what you are doing and what the actual problem is.